# How to write a generic functor which works without any condition and also with a condition (both for true and false)?

Tags: c++

I have three functors as given below. I want to combine them into one if possible. I am also giving their use cases.

```
struct ElemsCombine1 {
    Special s;

    Elems operator()(const Elems& acc, const auto& it) const
    {
        Special p = *it;
        Elems later_element;
        later_Element = this->l.get(p);
        Elems result;

        for (auto a : acc) {
            for (auto n : later_element) {
                result.push_back(a.join(n, s));
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
};

struct ElemsCombine2 {
    Special s;
    WtoN& turn;

    Elems operator()(const Elems& acc, const auto& it) const
    {
        Special p = *it;
        Elems later_element;
        later_Element = this->l.get(p);

        if (this->ab.net(p) <= turn) {
            Elems result;

            for (auto a : acc) {
                for (auto n : later_element) {
                    result.push_back(a.join(n, s));
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
        else return acc;
    }
};

struct ElemsCombine3 {
    Special s;
    WtoN& turn;

    Elems operator()(const Elems& acc, const auto& it) const
    {
        Special p = *it;
        Elems later_element;
        later_Element = this->l.get(p);

        if (this->ab.net(p) > turn) {
            Elems result;

            for (auto a : acc) {
                for (auto n : later_element) {
                    result.push_back(a.join(n, s));
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
        else return acc;
    }
};

target_fun(Wto& v)
{
    Special s = v.node();
    Elems initial_element;
    const WtoN& turn = this->cd.net(s);
    initial_element = this->m.get(s);
    auto comb1 = ElemsCombine1();
    comb1.s = s;
    Elems E = std::accumulate(pre_begin(s), pre_end(s), *initial_element, comb1);

    auto comb2 = ElemsCombine2();
    comb2.s = s;
    comb2.turn = turn;
    Elems E = std::accumulate(pre_begin(s), pre_end(s), *initial_element, comb2);

    auto comb3 = ElemsCombine3();
    comb3.s = s;
    comb3.turn = turn;
    Elems E = std::accumulate(pre_begin(s), pre_end(s), *initial_element, comb3);
}
```

Notice that the only difference between three functors `ElemsCombine1`, `ElemsCombine2` and `ElemsCombine3` is the if conditional statement inside them. Please tell me how I can combine the 3 functors into one. If it is not possible to combine the without if statement functor `ElemsCombine1` with if statement functors `ElemsCombine2` and `ElemsCombine3`, that is also acceptable.

Comment: ```std::optional```?

Comment: Can you explain the `const auto& it` parameter? That's not valid C++.

Comment: @NikosC. Please tell me what is wrong with it. If possible suggest the correct version.

Comment: Well, what's wrong is that it doesn't compile, obviously. An `auto` function parameter is not allowed. You either need to add overloads of `operator()`, each with its own type for `it`, or you need to make the operator a template: `template<typename Iterator> Elems operator()(const Elems& acc, const Iterator& it) const`

Answer (score 2):

You might factorize code with a functor, something like:

```
template <typename F>
struct ElemsCombine {
    Special s;
    F f;

    Elems operator()(const Elems& acc, const auto& it) const
    {
        Special p = *it;
        Elems later_element;
        later_Element = this->l.get(p);

        if (f(p)) { return acc; }
        Elems result;

        for (auto a : acc) {
            for (auto n : later_element) {
                result.push_back(a.join(n, s));
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
};
```

And then just have your 3 conditions functor (possibly as lambda):

```
struct always_false
{
    bool operator(const Special&) const { return false;}
};

struct Foo3
{
    WtoN& turn;

    bool operator(const Special& p) const { return this->ab.net(p) > turn;}

};

struct Foo2
{
    WtoN& turn;

    bool operator(const Special& p) const { return this->ab.net(p) <= turn;}
};
```

and then

```
ElemsCombine<always_false> ElemsCombine1{s};
ElemsCombine<Foo2> ElemsCombine2{s, {turn}};
ElemsCombine<Foo3> ElemsCombine3{s, {turn}};
```

Comment: Why not just use lambdas instead of `Foo3` etc.? Edit: Ok you said "possibly as lambda" but why all this work? :D

Comment: @MaxLanghof: Mostly depend if "condition" type are reused or not. As OP had 3 structures, I suppose that OP still want to have those, but factorized.

Comment: @Jarod42 Please suggest the `std::accumulate` line also. Should I write `ElemsCombine1{s}` or `ElemsCombine1` in place of `comb1` and so on? I also did not understand about your mentioning of lambda. I know that lambdas are the functors present directly in the code but I am not sure about current case.